# How to make a path-agnostic alias for zsh?

Tags: alias, zsh

I'm using [hsenv](https://github.com/Paczesiowa/hsenv). To activate it I need to do this:

```
cd ~/projects/foo
hsenv
source .hsenv_foo/bin/activate
```

I'm looking for a way to replace third command with an alias. The problem is there's a path-dependent component in the path to `activate` script.

How can I replace the `foo` in `.hsenv_foo` by the name of actual directory that I'm currently in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it in an alias, but you can wrap it in a function:

```
function my-hsenv { 
    # If we want the full path
     # foo=`pwd`;
    # If we want only the name of the current dir
    foo=$(basename $(pwd))
    source .hsenv_${foo}/bin/activate
}
```

Then run `my-hsenv`:

```
$ my-hsenv
my-hsenv:source:5: no such file or directory: .hsenv_tmp/bin/activate
```

But you get the idea.

Comment: Great, thanks.
I've also discovered that `hsenv` steps back from its documentation and actually uses just `.hsenv` folder.